# Can't get shell script to run in Xcode

Tags: xcode, shell

I'm fairly new to running scripts in Xcode and haven't been able to figure out whats wrong with the script I'm running. The first script I ran was this:

```
/bin/sh -x

PBXCP=${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
${PBXCP} -exclude .svn "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../base" 
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
```

Which caused me to run into this error:

```
/Users/newperson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-etesgjzdmfzimlgvakidckjecgij
/Build
/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.build/Script-
435F41A90F532CA300887552.sh: line 3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp: No such file or directory
```

This error was fairly to the point, The file the script is looking for doesn't exist. The newer versions of Xcode have gotten rid of pbxcp. So I started looking for a good alternative script to run that wouldn't use pbxcp, when I found this:

```
/bin/sh -x

/usr/bin/tar -c -C "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" --exclude .DS_Store --exclude CVS --exclude
.svn --exclude .git -H `cd "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" && find DevToolsCore.framework` | 
/usr/bin/tar -x -C ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}
```

This script also caused me to run into a problem, which was this:

```
tar: could not chdir to '/Users/newperson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-
etesgjzdmfzimlgvakidckjecgij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.app/Frameworks'

tar: Write error
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I couldn't find a clear answer to what this error meant, one forum suggest that I use the sudo command in my script to give the script permission to change directory, so I ran this:

```
/bin/sh -x

/usr/bin/tar -c -C "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" --exclude .DS_Store --exclude CVS --exclude
.svn --exclude .git -H `cd "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" && find DevToolsCore.framework`
| sudo /usr/bin/tar -x -C ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}
```

This script caused me to run into this error though:

```
tar: Write error
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
++ find DevToolsCore.framework
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
tar: Write error
```

This is as far as I got so far, I am fairly lost with my limited knowledge of shell script so any help correcting my script or finding a suitable replacement for the Xcode framework that contains pbxcp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of the directory where your script wants to write files. Do it in an interactive session of Terminal:

```
 $ sudo chmod a+w the_directory
```

Then you should be able to run your script (without `sudo`ing the `tar`).